How to create a loop to check the inputs of character that match a preset word (Hangman Game)?
Can anyone help me to create a loop for users to continuously input until all alphabetics are guessed right? I would like to keep the while True loop for the input checking (isalpha() and length = 1). For now, it does not loop until all letters guessed right and it seems impossible to nest a while True loop in another while True loop.
print("Let's Play Hangman game!")

while True:
    vocab = input("Please enter an English word: ")
    if vocab.isalpha():
        uppercase_vocab = vocab.upper()
        break
    else:
        print(f"Your input'{vocab}'is not a valid English word.")


display = []
for _ in range(len(uppercase_vocab)):
    display += "_"
#print (display)

while True:
    word = input("Please enter an Alphabetic: ")
    if len(word) == 1 and word.isalpha():
        uppercase_word = word.upper()
        break
    else:
        print(f"Your input'{word}'is not an Alphabet。")


for i in range(len(uppercase_vocab)):
    letter = uppercase_vocab[i]
    if letter == uppercase_word:
        display[i] = letter

combine = "".join(display)

print(f"Your input is correct: {combine}")


and it seems impossible to nest a while true loop in another while true loop Nonsense.

You need a loop that checks if all the letters have been guessed correctly.

How about simply checking if the current user word matches the solution? Also, you use terms recklessly. A bunch of your alleged "words" are letters. Your use of the term "Alphabet(ic)" is nonsensical.

Yes, what @OysterShucker said.  It's better to use a variable name that clearly expresses its intended function, such as letter.

You need two loops. One for acquiring the word and another to get the letters that you want to try to match in the word.
Something like this:
while not (word := input("Please enter a word: ").lower()).isalpha():
    print(f"'{word}' is not valid. Try again")

result = ["_"] * len(word)

while True:
    letter = input("Enter a single letter: ").lower()
    if len(letter) != 1 or not letter.isalpha():
        print(f"'{letter}' is not a valid letter. Try again")
    else:
        for i, w in enumerate(word):
            if letter == w:
                result[i] = letter
        # join with spaces for readability
        print(" ".join(result))
        if not "_" in result:
            print("You win")
            break


Instead of using break in your while True loop, you could put the for loop in there, so your code would look something like this:
while True:
word = input("Please enter an Alphabetic: ")
if len(word) == 1 and word.isalpha():
    uppercase_word = word.upper()
    for i in range(len(uppercase_vocab)):
        letter = uppercase_vocab[i]
        if letter == uppercase_word:
            display[i] = letter
        if not "_" in display:
            combine = "".join(display)
            print(f"Your input is correct: {combine}")
            exit(0)
else:
    print(f"Your input'{word}'is not an Alphabet。")

As statement to end the code, you could use:
if not "_" in display:
            combine = "".join(display)
            print(f"Your input is correct: {combine}")
            exit(0)

which ends the program, if there are no more unguessed characters in your display variable.

When posting an "answer" please ensure at least 2 things. 1) That it's formatted properly (i.e., runnable) and 2) That it achieves the stated objective
